# Objective C: Missing border for UIBarButton in toolbar

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I was trying to create a UIBarButton and add it to a tool bar using code. I fount the border of my button missing after running the app. My code as shown below.

[image: UIBarButton without border]

```
//Add toolbar to the UITable View
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 50);

//Set the toolbar to fit the width of the app.
[toolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *flexButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                           target:nil 
                                                                           action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Who Paid?" 
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:nil];

NSArray *buttonItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:flexButton, nextButton, nil];

[self.toolbar setItems:buttonItems];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];


[buttonItems release];
[flexButton release];
[nextButton release];
[toolbar release];
```

Am I missing out on any step or is there a mistake that was made? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Zhen

Comment: Have you tried a style other than `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` for the button?

Comment: Yup thanks! I found one with a border. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` is the culprit.

According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html), **`UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`** is what you need :

> `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` : Glows when
>   tapped. The default item style.
>
> **`UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`** : A simple
>   button style with a border.
>
> `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` : The style for
>   a done button—for example, a button
>   that completes some task and returns
>   to the previous view.

Comment: Great thanks! I found another one which says bordered. Silly me.